# Recycler view strange behaviour when height is match_parent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

I am facing an strange behaviour now days. I am using view binding for refrencing ids. When RecyclerView height is wrap_content the item display perfectly but when I set recyclerview height match_parent the item width is automatically wrapped (wrap_content) in run time but in xml I have set item width is match_parent.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Please look at my xml and kt files -:

```
<LinearLayou ------
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRvTrainerReview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTvDate"
        style="@style/MediumText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="14 feb"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTvStartTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="19:30" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

adapter file -:

```
class FeedbackDataAdapter(
    private var mcontext: Context,
    private var mItemList: MutableList<ResponseTrainerFeedback.Result.Training>,
    var mClickListener: OnClickListener?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TrainingDataViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TrainingDataViewHolder {
       var layoutInflater =   mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as (LayoutInflater)
        val rowEventMemberBinding =
            RowEventDataBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return TrainingDataViewHolder(rowEventMemberBinding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int =  mItemList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TrainingDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.mBinding.idTvDate.text = mItemList[holder.adapterPosition].trainingName
        holder.mBinding.idTvStartTime.invisible()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if(mItemList.size > 0){
                mClickListener?.onItemClick(holder.adapterPosition)
            }
        }

    }

    fun refreshList(mFeedbackList: MutableList<ResponseTrainerFeedback.Result.Training>) {
        this.mItemList = mFeedbackList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}

class TrainingDataViewHolder(var mBinding: RowEventDataBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mBinding.root) {

}
```

[image]

Comment: could you add the full version of your adapter ? I don't understand why you're calling `mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as(LayoutInflater)` when you can simply use `LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)` in your adapter

Comment: I have used both but i am getting same result also Added adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and It's working.

I've only refactored your adapter according to [Android training](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/master/RecyclerViewDiffUtilDataBinding/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepNightAdapter.kt) and if you want to do the codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TrainingDataViewHolder {
       return TrainingDataViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int =  mItemList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TrainingDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(mItemList[position])
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if(mItemList.size > 0){
                mClickListener?.onItemClick(holder.adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

    fun refreshList(mFeedbackList: MutableList<ResponseTrainerFeedback.Result.Training>) {
        this.mItemList = mFeedbackList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}

class TrainingDataViewHolder(var mBinding: RowEventDataBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mBinding.root) {

    fun bind(data: YOURDATA) {
        mBinding.idTv = data // it'll map automatically all the property, replace idTv by the name of your variable in your layout
        mBinding.idTvStartTime.invisible()
    }


    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): TrainingDataViewHolder {
            return TrainingDataViewHolder(RowEventDataBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
        }
    }

}
```

**row_item**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="idTv"
            type="package.name.to.data" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTvDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="@{idTv.idTvDate}"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="14 feb"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTvStartTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="19:30" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

PS: I don't see `<layout>` in your `row_item`, are you sure you're doing binding correctly ?

[image]

Comment: I am not using data binding so i don't need to add layout tag in xml. I am using viewbinding. Please check with viewBinding.

Comment: This `val rowEventMemberBinding = RowEventDataBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)` is from `databinding` : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#binding_data

Comment: Its same in viewbinding also. you can check doc of viewbinding. The file name is row_event_data that why it has generated RowEventDataBinding. If the file name is row_event then it will genereate RowEventBinding.

Comment: Oh indeed, I learned something, my bad, but as you can see in the screen your layout is totally fine. Is your `recyclerview` nested in a `view` ?

Comment: Yes, I am having this problem everywhere in recycler view so I have to set height wrap_content in recycler view only then it works fine.